# Launch4j (jar to exe), трудно ли получить исходный код из созданного exe файла?

Tags: java

Launch4j.
Программа делает из jar exe файлы.
Насколько трудно получить из такого exe исходный код?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку Launch4j это не компилятор, а оборачиватель (wrapper) jar в exe, то лишь немного сложнее, чем сгенерировать java-файлы из непосредственно jar при помощи декомпилятора (jad или тому подобного).

Если требования по использованию API не слишком велики, то можно посмотреть в сторону проектов, компилирующих Java в нативный код, но там не всё хорошо, конечно, но защита будет получше.

Comment: Спасибо. А о название проекта какое-нибудь напишите.